# Does freezer burn affect only the cells on the surface of food?

Tags: biochemistry, food, temperature, food-chemistry

Suppose i submerge a banana halfway through in a tray with water. Part of the banana is submerged in water, part of it is on the outside. The water and banana in the tray is being put in the freezer and freeze. Since part of the banana is exposed to air freezer burn is going to take place. How deep does it affect the tissue?

Not a homework question.